# How to provide a low response time <1µs constant current source up to 1.5A

Tags: power-supply, constant-current, high-frequency, frequency-response

I need to provide a constant current source that can provide up to 1.5A current and a compliant voltage of 0-40V, with a low response time of <1µs. How should I approach this problem?

Common bench power supply or driver IC has a much higher response time.

The reason to have a low response time is to provide the power supply suggested in [How to convert low voltage digital signal (0-3.3V) to high power current signal 15-40W ranging from 1kHz to 1MHz?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/677050/how-to-convert-low-voltage-digital-signal-0-3-3v-to-high-power-current-signal#answer-677059).

Comment: 1) Does the current have to be programmable or adjustable?  2) What accuracy do you need in the current?  3) What does the load looks like?  Big difference between driving a resistive load and a large inductive one.

Comment: 1) It needs to be adjustable but does not need to be programmable.
2) No specific accuracy requirement, but it needs to be consistent, as this is used to power an LED so that the illuminance level is stable.

Comment: Actually being adjustable is not a must. I can use PWM dimming instead.

Comment: Where does your 1us requirement come from?

Comment: Have a look at LT3743, this is a power LED modulator and covers most of your requirements.